# Attempt to write a readonly database in flex ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, apache-flex, sqlite, flex4

I have an application made ​​in flex.
My problem is when I run a query to update on my iphone, the console return:

```
Attempt to write a readonly database.
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey have you seen this adobe post:
http://forums.adobe.com/message/3793410

Basically claims that:

> - on iOS your application directory is "read-only" (at least when using native applicaiton) - so resources in application directory (in
>     terminology of Air SDK - not iOS SDK) cannot be
>     modified/written/updated
> - you could ship already created sqlite database file with your application but it should be copied into application writable
>     directory - e.g. to documents. This directory can be accessed via:
>
>   File.documentsDirectory
> - so when your application starts you could do following:
>
> 1) construct path to documents directory database path
>
> 2) check if database in that path exists (if File exists)
>
> 3) if file does not exists yet either copy it into that path from
>   application resources directory (where you bundle it when building
>   project) OR create new empty database using all those CREATE table and
>   then INSERT statements required to create new fresh copy of database
>
> 4) on each next startup if checking if file exists at #2 skip database
>   creation/copy and simply start using it.